# Problem generating JSON using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to generate following Json result. I have generated most of the output except "Attributes" and could not figure it out how to do it. Result is requested by client and cannot be change.

Expected result.

```
{
    "TransactionId": "3S76CjmZ3S7",
    "Environment": "sandbox",
    "ApiVersion": "1.0",
    "Error": "",
    "Warning": "",
    "Data_response": {
        "Data_response_data": [{
            "Brand": "Genuine",
            "Number": "E11106660",
            "Description": "DUPLICATE BASE",
            "Images": [{
                    "FileName": "EA10650_STO_FRO_ALL.PNG"
                },
                {
                    "FileName": "EA10660_STO_FRO_ALL.png"
                }
            ],
            "360Images": [{
                "FileName": "EA10660_STO_ALL.zip"
            }],
            "OriginalStrings": "E11106660",
            "Attributes": {
                "Color": "Blue",
                "Weight": "120lbs",
                "Brand": "TRP"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I am using following code to generate json.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    TransactionId = partRequest.TransactionId,
    Environment = partRequest.Environment,
    ApiVersion = partRequest.ApiVersion,
    Error = "",
    Warning = "",
    Data_response = new
    {
        Data_response_data =
             from p in Wrapper
             orderby p.CompressedNumber
             select new
             {
                 Brand = p.Brand,
                 Number = p.CompressedNumber,
                 Description = p.Description,
                 Images =
                     from d in p.DigitalAssets
                     orderby d.FileName
                     select new
                     {
                         FileName = d.FileName
                     },
                 360Images =
                     from d in p.DigitalAssets360
                     orderby d.FileName
                     select new
                     {
                         FileName = d.FileName
                     },
                 OriginalStrings = p.CompressedNumber,
                 Attributes = ???
                 // I tried this but its throws an exception.
                 // from d in p.Attributes
                 // orderby d.Name
                 // select new
                 // {
                 //  d.Name = d.Value
                 //}
             }
    }
});
```

Attribute class

```
public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For many years, Visual Studio has had the ability to create the classes necessary to produce or read JSON: Copy the valid JSON to the clipboard, then **Edit Menu** >> **Paste Special** >> **Paste JSON as Classes**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes need to be transformed into a dictionary.

## Example

```
class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get ; set; }
}

(...)

var attributes = new List<Attribute>
{
    new Attribute() { Name="Color", Value="Blue" },
    new Attribute() { Name= "Weight", Value ="54.4kg" }
};

var d = attributes.ToDictionary(a=> a.Name, a => a.Value);

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { Attributes = d});

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

## Output

```
{"Attributes":{"Color":"Blue","Weight":"54.4kg"}}
```

---

In your case it could be something like the following.

```
Attributes = (from d in p.Attributes
                  orderby d.Name
                 select d).ToDictionary(a=> a.Name, a => a.Value)
```